# Updating part of page (one page model)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

i'm creating a simple page with listing data from database and I would like to create the option of editing a selected row by transferring the row data into a form.
Then the user can update the data and submit the form.

The problem might be that i'm using the same form for inserting and editing data (depending whether objectID is null or not).

I managed to refresh both parts of the page by using ko.applyBindings(PAGMODEL, DOM_ELEMENT), but i'm having trouble displaying data when user needs to find and load data with 'livesearch'/'autocomplete' (I get the data, it just won't show on html)

Code:

```
function MedicalCentersPM(parameters) {
var self = this;

self.MyModelArray = ko.observableArray();
self.MyModelToManipulate = new MyModel();

self.SearchQuery = ko.observable('');

self.loadData = function () {
    loadDataRowsSync(
        parameters.filter,
        self.SearchQuery(),
        '',
        function () {
            self.MyModelArray.removeAll();
        },
        function (jsonData) {
            $.each(jsonData, function (i, mc) {
                self.MyModelArray.push(new MyModel(mc));
            });
        }
    );

    /// UPDATING HTML (ONE WAY)
    try {
        ko.applyBindings(self, parameters.dataDOM);
    } catch (exc) { }
};
self.manipulateRow = function () {
    axaxManipulationCall(
        parameters.manipulationUrl,
        ko.toJSON(self.MyModelToManipulate),
        function () {
            self.resetForm();
            self.loadData();
        },
        function (message) {
            alert(message);
        }
    );
};

self.selectRow = function (row) {
    self.MyModelToManipulate(MyModel(ko.toJS(row)));

    ko.cleanNode(parameters.formDOM);
    ko.applyBindings(self, parameters.formDOM);
};

self.resetForm = function () {
    self.MyModelToManipulate = new MyModel(JSON.parse(parameters.defaultModel));

    ko.cleanNode(parameters.formDOM);
    ko.applyBindings(self, parameters.formDOM);
};
self.messageRow = function () {
    alert(ko.toJSON(self.MyModelToManipulate));
    return false;
};

self.loadData();
self.resetForm();
};
```

JSFiffle: http://jsfiddle.net/cbpedmh4/5/

I might be doing something very wrong or I missed some small detail.... so...
Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: We need all of the related code that you have so far and a specific problem statement.  Currently this question doesn't contain enough information for us to reproduce the issue you're facing.

Comment: I tried two ways of editing data:
- using method: self.selectRow(row){
self.ModelToEdit(row);
}
- using method: self.selectRow(row){
self.ModelToEdit = new MyModel(ko.ToJS(row));
}

when using method no2 i had to reload parts of html page with ko.appyBindings(MODEL, dom)

and when using method no1 i, the data was successfully 'copied' but i couldn't see it on html :(

and yes, i'm using jQuery ajax to retreive data to MODEL collection

i hope this helps...
if not, please say what else might be more helpful..

thank you

Comment: Please can you add that code and the details to the question :), it'll make it clearer then

Comment: Ok, I added the snippet of code :)

Comment: I have just read your question, saw the fiddle and I have no clue what is the issue. Make it simple, what is not working in the fidlde, that you think your code does?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. If you click on "Edit" in first row, you can see that the field with the name "Description" and "Opis" does not update.